# Relationship between the side lengths of a tetrahedron and an inscribed tetrahedron with vertices at the centroids

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometry, platonic-solids

> Suppose that $OABC$ is a regular tetrahedron with sides having centroids $\lbrace E,F,G,H\rbrace$ also forming a regular tetrahedron. What is the relationship between the side lengths of $OABC$ and $EFGH$?

I suspect that tetrahedron $EFGH$ has side lengths $1/3$ of that of $OABC$ but I'm unsure as to how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The centroid of the face $ABC$ is $\frac13(A+B+C)$.  The centroid of the whole large tetrahedron is $\frac14(O+A+B+C)$.  Note that
$$ \tfrac14(O+A+B+C) = \tfrac14 O + \tfrac34 (\tfrac13(A+B+C)) $$
This shows that the centroid of the large tetrahedron is $\frac34$ of the way along the line segment from the vertex $O$ to the centroid of the opposite face.  Thus the distance from the centroid of the large tetrahedron to the centroid of the face is $\frac13$ of the distance to the vertex $O$.  Now, $O$ was arbitrary, so the analogous statement is true for each vertex and the centroid of its opposite face.  Thus the little tetrahedron can be obtained from the large one by scaling (with centre the centroid of the big tetrahedron) by $-\frac13$.

(Compare the fact that the medians of a triangle concur at its centroid, which lies $\frac23$ of the way along each median.  In fact this argument generalizes to $n$ dimensions quite readily.)

Comment: Can you please clarify the sentence "Thus the distance from the centroid of the large triangle to the centroid of the..." What is the large triangle?

Comment: Thanks Steven for your clear solution.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio of the edge-lengths is equal to the ratio of the circumradii. Since the *insphere* of $ABCD$ is tangent to the faces at the centroids, it is also the *circumsphere* of $EFGH$. As [Wikipedia notes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Regular_tetrahedron), 
$$\text{inradius of regular tetrahedron} = \frac13 \cdot \text{circumradius of regular tetrahedron}$$
so your suspicion is correct.

Comment: Thanks Blue. But how would one prove that the ratio of the edge lengths equals the ratio of the circumradii?

Comment: The tetrahedra are *similar*, so corresponding lengths are *proportional* by a common scale factor. The fact that $EFGH$'s circumradius is one-third that of $ABCD$ says that $EFGH$ is the result of *shrinking* $ABCD$ by a factor of $1/3$; this scale factor applies to all corresponding lengths (edges, altitudes, medians-of-a-face, ... whatever). Note that the *square* of the scale factor relates corresponding areas (say, of faces), and the *cube* of the scale factor relates corresponding volumes.

Comment: Yes, agreed. But specifically, how does one know that the common scale factor is $1/3$? In particular, how does one prove the equality you have cited from Wikipedia?

Comment: To prove the inradius-circumradius relation, consider this: let $X$ be the center of $ABCD$ and let $Y$ be center of the face opposite $A$. Certainly, the volume of $YBCD$ is $1/4$ the volume of $ABCD$, but it has the same "base", $\triangle BCD$; therefore, (since volume is 1/3 area-of-base, times height) $X$'s distance from $Y$ must be $1/4$ of $A$'s distance from $Y$: $|AY| = 4|XY|$. But, then, $|AX| = \frac34 |AY| = 3|XY|$. Since $|AX|$ is the circumradius, and $|XY|$ the inradius, the relation is established.